# How to use a SQL query result as an object in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm creating a data analysis process in c# using EF (code first). The data model involves about a dozen interrelated classes.  Most of these directly correspond with tables in an existing database, but a couple key read-only object types are really the product of complex, multi-step SQL queries.  I can't create a view or stored proc for the query.

I'd like to be able to use something like DbSet.SqlQuery() to load those query results into EF objects, and still leverage EF's ORM features to relate them with the rest of the object graph.

I think what I want is a way to override EF's SQL SELECT code when the DbSet tries to populate that query-based object from the database. Is this possible?  Is there a better alternative approach?

Comment: it WOULD be possible, if you used multiple contexts. Since the specific context instance determines the queries calculated when you hit a table and ultimately also the foreign key constraints, you could use another context where you map only the properties you query and in between those foreign key constraints. Once you switch between contexts, you'll have to join in memory though.

Comment: did you have  a look on the interceptors?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro thanks Devil, though I'm not sure I'm following you why a second context would be helpful.

Comment: @HadiHassan thanks, following your suggestion I did look at interception.  Promising idea, but I had a hard time finding docs to guide me through my use case.  I think I have a workaround now (see accepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way that's working for me, but it's hacky.  (Is there a better way?)

Let's say Foo is a poco class that corresponds with an expensive query result that I want to explicitly write in SQL and use as an object in a read-only EF object graph. Foo includes foreign keys and navigation properties. My dbContext has a DbSet called Foos.

```
// Pre-req: prevent EF from trying to sync model with db, since Foos doesn't map to a db table.
public FooDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<FooDbContext>(null); 
}

// load the query data with SqlQuery() and Attach()
var foos = db.Foos.SqlQuery("<hand written SQL SELECT>", parameters);
foreach(var foo in foos) db.Foos.Attach(foo);

// Subsequently reference the data with .Local to prevent db hits (which would fail, since no Foo table in db.)
var result = db.Foos.Local.Select(...);
```

I do have to explicitly load related objects, but then all the relationship association happens automatically. For example let's say Bar has a 1-to-many with Foo, Foo has a BarId property (and a Bar navigation property) and maybe the Bar class has an observable collection of Foos.  If Bars is stored as a db lookup table, I could just do db.Bars.Load(), or something more filtered like:

```
var barIds = db.Foos.Local.Select(f => f.BarId).Distinct().ToArray();
db.Bars.Where(b => barIds.Contains(b.barId)).Load();
```

Then I can use Foo.Bar or Bar.Foos and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps write your arbitrary query into a stored procedure? You could then use Entity framework to map that to a function.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use stored procs or views for this.  But even if I could, it doesn't seem that those results are "tracked" by EF, which in my case amounts to having relationships set with the rest of the object graph.